# Symfony ChoiceType To Accept JSON Request Body

Tags: php, json, api, symfony, symfony-forms

I am creating a Symfony API. I have the following Form Type to accept a JSON Request Body:

```
$builder
        ->add('email', Type\EmailType::class)
        ->add('username', Type\TextType::class)
        ->add('name', Type\TextType::class)
        ->add('plainPassword', Type\RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => Type\PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
        ))
        ->add('types', Type\ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'Photographer' => 'Photographer',
            ],
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true
        ])
    ;
```

And I send the JSON Body like so:

```
{"username": "merchant2", "email": "merchant2@gmail.com", "plainPassword": {"first": "gerlie" , "second": "gerlie"}, "name": "merchant2", "types": ["Photographer"]}
```

The form then validate it with errors telling me:

> The value you selected is not a valid choice.

This is caused by ConstraintValidationExcetption.

Note that I also got assert on my entity like so:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Choice({"Event Organizer", "Photographer", "Host", "Catering", "Band", "Others"})
 */
private $types;
```

Why does this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your controller code from when you feed the data to the form.

Comment: Surely due to prefix of your Form. To see what it should look like, create a fake view and render yoru form with form_render to see input's name